# Unable to get results for list of AD groups but works for single AD group using windows powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to prepare a script that will display all the AD groups from the input file having one specific service account. I mean, if I have some AD groups in Groups.txt file and I give this as input to a script that checks if any of those groups have a service account (ABC) then we get the output of only those groups that have ABC service account. Below is the script I tried but it doesn't work

```
$groups = Get-Content C:\Groups.txt
$results = foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity serviceaccountname |
       select -ExpandProperty Name | Where-object { $_ -like '*$group*'} | Sort}
$results
```

However, this script works if I just use 1 group by hardcoding the group name like below

```
$results = foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity serviceaccountname |
       select -ExpandProperty Name | Where-object { $_ -like '*GroupName*'} | Sort}
```

There could be some syntax error, I am unable to figure it out. It would be great if someone can help me with this.

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: Single quotes are for verbatim strings. If you want a variable to be substituted with a value within a string, then you must surround your string with double quotes. I’m this case though, you don’t need any quotes at all. Since you are looking for an exact match, you should use `-eq`.

Comment: PLEASE, wrap your code [and sample data/errors, if any] in code formatting. the instructions for that are linked on the page you used to create your Question.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this another way using [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7) and only query AD once.

```
$groups = Get-Content C:\Groups.txt
$membership = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity serviceaccountname | Select -Expand Name
$results = $membership | Compare-Object $groups -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent |
    Select -Expand InputObject | Sort
```

---

You need an expandable string if you want a variable inside to be substituted with a value. Single-quoted strings are literal strings. Double-quoted strings allow interpolation to happen inside. So `'$groups'` will return the text `$groups`, and `"$groups"` will return the value of `$groups`. However, quotes are unnecessary in this case if you are looking for exact matches. For exact matches, it is more efficient to use `-eq` in favor of `-like`. Following these ideas, your code would be modified to the following:

```
$groups = Get-Content C:\Groups.txt
$results = foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity serviceaccountname |
        select -ExpandProperty Name | Where-object { $_ -eq $group } | Sort
}
```

You can take this a step further and improve efficiency by removing the need for looping. This can be done with the containment [operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7).

```
$groups = Get-Content C:\Groups.txt
$results = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity serviceaccountname |
        Select -ExpandProperty Name | Where-object { $_ -in $groups } | Sort
}
```

---

If you were to follow examples provided by [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7), you can see differences between double quoted and single quoted strings. Here is a trivial example:

```
PS> $str = "mystring"
PS> '$str' # Single quotes = No substitution
$str
PS> "$str" # Double quotes = Substitution
mystring
PS> $str # No quotes = substitution
mystring
```